# Method from another GUI didn't work using PyQT 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have menu_utama.py which has UI in menu_utama_ui.py (converting result from qt designer) and rekam_mhs.py which has UI in rekam_mhs_ui.py.

The source code of menu_utama.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from menu_utama_ui import  Ui_Form
from rekam_mhs import rekam_mhs_form

class Main_Program(Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self,dialog):
        rekam_mhs_form.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(dialog)

        #Connect "add" button with a custom function
        self.btnMhs.clicked.connect(self.fungsiMahasiswa)

    def fungsiMahasiswa(self):
        dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        dialog.ui = rekam_mhs_form() #call rekam_mhs.py
        dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()

    prog = Main_Program(dialog)

    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here some source code in rekam_mhs.py

```
import sys
import database as db

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from rekam_mhs_ui import  rekam_mhs_form
from model import mahasiswa

class rekam_mhs_main(rekam_mhs_form):

    def __init__(self,dialog):
        rekam_mhs_form.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(dialog)
        self.btnGetData.clicked.connect(self.fungsiPushButton)  #problem

        #Connect "add" button with a custom function

    def fungsiGetData(self): 
        #To call some data from database
        txt = self.lineEdit.text()
        res = db.Database().select_NIM(txt)
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(""+res.nama)
        self.lineEdit_4.setText(""+res.kelas)
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(""+res.prodi)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    prog = rekam_mhs_main(dialog)
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run "python3 rekam_mhs.py" and click the button (btnGetData), the method is called (fungsiGetData) and executed.

When I run "python3 menu_utama.py" and click the button (btnMhs) to call rekam_mhs.py, the GUI is shown up but when I click btnGetData, the method (fungsiGetData) is not executed. This condition kinda like there is no method when that button is clicked.

What did I miss? Do I do wrong to call another GUI by that way? I've searched some tutorial but using qt4 instead of qt5.

Comment: what is `rekam_mhs_form`?

Comment: class name from rekam_mhs.py

Comment: As I see in rekam_mhs.py the class rekam_mhs_main inherits from the class rekam_mhs_form, but I do not see where you have defined rekam_mhs_form, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I've edited the code

Comment: please take the time and read that it is a [mcve], its code is not because it is not complete: there are many that are not defined and it is not verifiable: because I can not execute it and consequently I can not observe the error you point out .

Comment: sorry, my mistakes. I've edited. Hopely, It explained well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code you provided, I'm pretty sure the problem is in the `fungsimahasiswa()` function. You are calling the `setupUi()` function twice( inside the `rekam_mhs_main` constructor and then inside `fungsimahasiswa()` too).

You are defining the Signal-slot `self.btnGetData.clicked.connect(self.fungsiPushButton)` within the constructor, but immediately you call `setupUi()` in `fungsimahasiswa()`. That causes a new `self.btnGetData` to be created. Then that new button will not have a Signal-Slot.

That's why I think the `fungsimahasiswa()` should be:

```
def fungsiMahasiswa(self):
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    dialog.ui = rekam_mhs_form(dialog)
    dialog.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation hit me something that I have wrongly input the class. Also, your code did work. Thanks.